# starting program via command line arguments

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm trying to start a program via the command line. I am working out of section 8.5: Command Line Arguments in C++ for Everyone. I built the program in netbeans.

How do I start the program from the command line? I am not sure where to find the program. I was expecting to find an .exe in the Documents\NetBeansProjects folder that I could run with the arguments, but I could not find one.

I am on windows 7.

Thanks!

**Where does Netbeans output the C++ executable?

(in addition, I may or may not be able to figure out how to run it once I find it. ~never used cmd line before)

Comment: Netbeans has the ability to start the program with arguments passed to it as well.

Comment: @birryree: While helpful for the moment, I think the OP should really be told where Netbeans places C++ executables.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can press [Win]+R and type/select cmd. For me, that's the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is some terminal under your OS. Try typing the full path of the executable in it.

Comment: He can't find the executable.  His question is, where does netbeans output C++ executables?

Comment: Ah thank you. There were a number of things I couldn't figure out, so I wasn't sure how to word what I wanted to do. This is it.

Answer (score 0):

To get a terminal, select start --> run --> enter cmd and press OK.

If "explorer" is still part of Windows 7, use that to search for the file. You can (or used to be able to run) explorer by pressing and holding the Windows key and then pressing the e key. From there, you can cd to the appropriate directory and enter the file name on the command line.